# Understanding locale class, locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid

Tags: c++, locale

I'm trying to using localisation support. I've written:

```
#include <locale>

auto my_loc = std::locale(""); // OK
auto mm_loc = std::locale("POSIX"); // OK

auto an_loc = std::locale("en");// terminate called after throwing an instance of 
                                //'std::runtime_error'  what():                  
                                //locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid

auto ann_loc = std::locale("jp");// terminate called after throwing an instance of 
                                 //'std::runtime_error'  what():                  
                                 //locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
int main()
{
}
```

Could you explain in a nutshell is what is locale class for? Why can't we construct it with `"en"`, `"jp"`, `"us"` or other strings?

Comment: Locales are containers of facets which are used to internationalize the I/O functionality of your streams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can't we construct it with "en", "jp", "us" or other strings?

Because those aren't valid locale designations on your machine. The set of acceptable locale names is not in any way specified by the standard. On a Linux machine, use

```
$ locale -a
```

to print all valid locale names. This prints

```
C
POSIX
de_DE
de_DE.iso88591
de_DE.iso885915@euro
de_DE.utf8
de_DE@euro
deutsch
german
```

in my case. Every locale listed works fine with `std::locale`.

You imbue `std::locale`s into streams like `cout`. Then you use facets like `std::money_put` to insert data in a local-specific way - for us germans it would use `.` as the thousands separator and `,` as the decimal point.